# how to get Facebook feeds for multiple ids iOS graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios6

I'm trying to get facebook feeds from multiple ids using the Facebook Graph API on ios6.  I don't think this will work though, as I'm trying to test it in the developers.facebook.com graph explorer tool, and it doesn't work.  Here's what I'm doing:

in the graph explorer  (where "my id" is my actual numerical id, etc.):

`/id="my id"/feed`   -->  this works

`/ids="my id"`,`"my friend's id"/feed`   --> this does not work, I get the error

> message": "(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist:
>   ids=,", 
>       "type": "OAuthException", 
>       "code": 803

Do I need to get the feed for all my friends and then filter by id?  That seems wasteful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you're formatting the query incorrectly

`ids` is a parameter to the query, not part of the path (which `/feed` is)

`/feed?ids=X,Y,Z` should work

Comment: @lgy I have try to used /feed?ids=X,Y,Z inside my application and I got the response like this 
{
X:{  data : [
{.......},{.......}]},
Y:{ data : [{........},
  ]}
 }

But I need this like 
{
data : [
{.......},
{.......},
{........},
  ]
 }

Can you help me please !!.

Comment: Switch your code to fetch the data for each ID separately, or change it to read the data for each of the requested IDs, both should be trivial - the option you asked for wouldn't make sense as it would mix data from multiple IDs in the same response array and you'd lose the ability to see which posts came from which ID